# Kafka fetch.max.bytes vs max.partition.fetch.bytes understanding

Tags: apache-kafka

Did I understand the difference between `fetch.max.bytes` and `max.partition.fetch.bytes` configs correctly:
1st one limits a whole fetch response (that could consists of several topic/partitions data)
2nd limits data from every single partition in that composite response

So, is there no sense to set 2nd one higher that 1st?

I have read confluent docs: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your understanding is correct. So, the default value of `fetch.max.bytes` (i.e 50 MB ) is also set higher than the `max.partition.fetch.bytes`(i.e. 1 MB).